# Python discord bot using discord.py problem

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot using the module discord.py, but I'm running into an issue and I'm unable to fix it. What I'm trying to do is that when someone pings the bot, he answers his prefix, I got that working with :

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if bot.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send("My prefix is **_#_**")
```

However none of the code after that works:

```
@bot.command(name="ping")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong! {0}'.format(round(bot.latency, 1)))

@bot.command(name='get')
async def get(ctx, arg: to_lower):
    if (arg == "taurine"):
        author = "CoolStar"
        version = "1.0.4"
        size = "31MB"
        url = "https://www.yot-dev.ml/ipas/taurine.ipa"
    if arg == "unc0ver":
        author = "Pwn20wnd"
        version = "6.1.2"
        size = "59MB"
        url = "https://www.yot-dev.ml/ipas/unc0ver.ipa"
    if arg == "cercube5":
        author = "Majd Alfhaily"
        version = "16.19.6"
        size = "101MB"
        url = "https://www.yot-dev.ml/ipas/unc0ver.ipa"
    @bot.event
    async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
        if get(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
            await ctx.send("Please enter a valid argument.")

    text.description = "**["+str.capitalize(arg)+" IPA download link]""("+url+")**\nAuthor: "+author+"\nVersion: "+version+"\nSize: "+size
    await ctx.send(embed=text)

bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

, so I cannot use any commands other than mentioning/pinging the bot.
Would be nice to know if it's possible to fix this.

Comment: Can you edit to add the code after that? It's hard to troubleshoot something that we can't see

Comment: Sure, I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add this here to your on_message command as described in the docs:

```
else:
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly, now I can mention the bot and run all my other commands!